# Best approach with regards to data storage in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I was wondering if I can use Storage class to manage data objects like List of objects and etc. What was the limitation for Storage class? When do I need to use the sqlLite?

Im currently creating an app that is for personal use. Not a network kind of thing app

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to use sqlLite if you're making queries on data (i.e. that lend themselves to SQL queries)*.

For storing locally, check out [this video about storing data](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---store-data-to-persistent-storage-storageexternalization.html) in codename one. In it he tells you how to store things locally, including vectors (a list of objects).

Do watch the video, but very, *very* briefly do either of:

1. Implement `Externalisable` (codename one class) for your class and
   then call `Storage.getInstance().writeObject("yourObjName",
   yourObj);`
2. Just write the values directly with writeObject such
   as: `Storage.getInstance().writeObject("yourSettingName", text);`

**Edit:**
*Lending to SQL queries: a relational database. A database you would need to perform JOINs on to get any meaningful query from. [According to codename one](http://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html) it should be used on "very large data handling" :

> The Database class abstracts the underlying SQLite of the device if available. Supported platforms for this feature are: IOS, Android, BB OS5+ and the Desktop Simulator (which supports only cursor forward navigation). The SQLite should be used for very large data handling, for small storage refer to Storage which is more portable.

Comment: I was referring to how and when to use SQLlite instead of a normal storage class. Is SQLlite not on a local storage? like it can be accessed by other users? I kind of get the idea that you tend to use it on queries but why would I do queries if I can store objects itself locally via Storage class? Please enlighten me on this. Thanks